# Sending an email notification when the status changes?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I make it so that when a job status gets changed to "Cancelled" it sends an email to me notifying me of the change after submitting?

```
<form action='phplib/job_update.php' method='post' id='new_job'>
       <label for='status'>Job Status</label>
        <select name='status' id='status'>
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM status";
            $result = mysqli_query($dbc3, $sql);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'";
                if($row['id'] == $data['status']) echo "selected='selected'";
                echo ">" . ucwords($row['name']) . "</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
</form>
```

What the form looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to send email with PHP, but I'll show you the simplest (assuming you're not using any libraries or frameworks). Modify the phplib/job_update.php script. After writing to the database (look for another `mysqli_query(...)` line) add the following code:

```
$cancelledCode = // Easiest way to find this is to view source in the HTML
if ($cancelledCode == $_POST['status']) {
    $to = 'you@example.com';
    $subject = 'Cancelled Job';
    $message = 'Yo, a job has been cancelled. ...';
    if (!mail($to, $subject, $message)) {
        // Error sending mail
    }
}
```

More information on the `mail()` function, including setting the FROM address, can be found at http://www.php.net/mail

Comment: There is a function thats been set that checks if there was a change and it looks like this.
        $sql2 .= checkifchanged('job_list', 'status', $_POST['status'], $job_num, $dbc3); Do I put the code you posted somewhere there?

Comment: @MikeOscarEcho I have no idea, you'd need to post the code for me to see. Additionally, this is a learning site, not a "do the work for me" site, so please be sure to indicate what you have tried and what problems you've encountered.

Comment: Lol I never asked you to do the work for me but my question above was dumb so I admit to that. I tried using it in the function that checks the status but that didn't work. I figure theres more to it since theres a mail2.php and gmail.php files which seem to be the ones sending emails. There's another page that sends out email notifications when files are posted so I'll look there for reference. Thanks anyway.